# shaping a bonsai from a semi dead olive tree

Tags: bonsai

I bought one of those pre-bonsai things. It lost all leaves and "died" but it came back to life this spring. It sprouted two single branches and I have no clue how to shape it in anything resembling a bonsai.

I'd like to get some small moyogui.. Any suggestions??

Here are some pics of the thing:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You said the tree was close to death, so my advice would be to leave the tree alone this year and let it regain strength. Health in trees comes from the root mass, so focus on watering the tree to encourage new root growth, which primarily occurs over autumn. If you reduce the foliage mass through pruning or styling the tree will have less energy to spend on root growth.

Next spring, before any new growth starts, you can apply wire to add some movement to the two branches you have. The increased root mass will drive the growth of new branches, which can be wired in autumn or the following spring. The will start to add some real shape and interest to the tree.